# Desktop not appearing after a change in xorg.conf

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, screen

I tried to install `nvidia-current` on my Ubuntu 12.04 because I didn't have the driver for it but it seemed that had no effect so I removed.  After that, I don't remember anymore, I tried to configure the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in the screen section because when I removed the Nvidia driver, my default screen mode `1920x1080` went to a low resolution but the problem is that I made this command with `ctrl+alt+F1` and used Vim but I have no success so I did it by the terminal of desktop. After the changes I made in the screen section, i.e I put the string '1920x1080' in the section, my computer just boot, the Ubuntu logo appears, but after that nothing appears more. No logon screen, nothing. I can see the screen is on but nothing appears. I am also trying to solve this with my Ubuntu Live CD but I can't also log on the Desktop. I think my Nvidia driver is currently be using but in mode "Fallback" (I saw this in the system information, before I rebooted).
So, what can I do to restore my screen to normal mode '1920x1080'? (remember that I have no access to my desktop. Also I tried to remove a file with `.xml` format in the .config/ because I saw that if I removed it the problem would gone, but didn't solve to me).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try again with ctrl+alt+F1 but use nano , easier to use than vim:type  nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf  Also, try this command: sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg

Comment: I will try but I have one problem: I can't get in any terminal. My Live CD shows the same problem, that the graphic cards & input devices are not configured properly and I need to this manually. There is some options to config the file, save the log or use generic graphic but none of them works. What I do?

Comment: Pressing simultaneously  ctrl+alt+F1 should switch your pc  to a terminal in which you can login and then type commands. Try also this command: sudo nvidia-xconfig

Comment: Ya, I got the terminal. I am logged as ubuntu@ubuntu but sudo dpkg-reconfigure.. prompts xserver-xorg is not installed. I tried sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg and it prompts W: Duplicate sources.list ... E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device), E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened. And the nvidia-xconfig: command not found. I remembered that when I installed nvidia-current I got this nvidia-xconfig...

Comment: huh, seem you boot from cd ? If yes, try normal boot

Comment: I just can have my terminal in cd. When booting by computer itself, just my ubuntu logo appears, it loads but logon screen doesn't appear. In cd boot, I can edit xorg.conf.failsafe. Sorry to take your time.. what I do. Is there any thread I can do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14849/discussion-between-vidcelluloid-and-laugeo).

Comment: I got my screen and desktop back but how do I change the resolution from 640x480 to 1920x1080? My xorg.conf (X configuration file) was generated by nvidia-xconfig